# create a function that receives a string with the name an array and then prints each element [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that will do something like this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
option = input('your option: ')
printElements(option)
```

So if the user writes 'list1', the function should print a b c

Comment: It's fundamentally unclear to me what you are asking. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Also, having a `set` of lists is impossible.

Comment: Do *not* use dynamic variables, rather, if you are trying to map strings to `list` objects, use a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate your variable and get the list you want.

```
printElements(ast.literal_eval(option))
```

A better way to do it would be to store your lists in a dictionary and then use `option` as a key:

```
d = {"list1": list1, "list2": list2}
printElements(d[option])
```

Comment: while this is "correct", it is fundamentally bad advice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Added another way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
list = input("Your option : ")
def printWords(list):
    for value in list:
        print(value)
```